# repackage failed: Unable to find main class when creating a library using Spring-Boot-Starter-Parent version 2.1.2.RELEASE

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-security

I created an example resource server in spring security with a library that contains the `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter`.  When I update the parent `spring-boot-starter-parent` in the pom for the library from 2.0.8 to 2.1.2 as well as the `spring-boot-maven-plugin` I get the dreaded `repackage failed: Unable to find main class`
Version 2.0.8 of the `spring-boot-starter-parent` doesn't have this issue.

Update:  This happens upon doing a mvn clean compile install.  A version of the code with parent 2.0.8 can be found [here](https://github.com/tlann/resource-config/blob/master/pom.xml).  Just change the pom.xml spring starter parent from 2.0.8 to 2.1.2.

My Library pom is as follows.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <groupId>com.example.utils.security</groupId>
  <artifactId>resource-config</artifactId>
  <version>1.0.1</version>
  <properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
  </properties>

  <parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.1.2.RELEASE</version>
    <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
  </parent>

  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
      <version>2.1.2.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
      <version>2.1.2.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-security-config</artifactId>
      <version>5.1.3.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-security-oauth2-jose</artifactId>
      <version>5.1.3.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.security/spring-security-oauth2-resource-server -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-security-oauth2-resource-server</artifactId>
      <version>5.1.3.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-security-web</artifactId>
      <version>5.1.3.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>

  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.2.RELEASE</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <goals>
              <goal>repackage</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
              <skip>true</skip>
            </configuration>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>

</project>
```

A class to define an annotation.

```
import com.example.utils.security.resource.autoconfig.ResourceServerConfig;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Import;

import java.lang.annotation.*;

@Target(ElementType.TYPE)
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Documented
@Import({ResourceServerConfig.class})
public @interface EnableExampleResourceServer {
}
```

The WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter

```
package com.example.utils.security.resource.autoconfig;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.core.PriorityOrdered;
import org.springframework.core.annotation.Order;
import org.springframework.http.HttpMethod;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableWebSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter;

@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@Order(PriorityOrdered.HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE + 500)
public class ResourceServerConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                .csrf().disable()
                .anonymous().disable()
                .logout().disable()
                .formLogin().disable()
                .httpBasic().disable()
                .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers(HttpMethod.OPTIONS).permitAll()
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and()
                .oauth2ResourceServer().jwt();
    }
}
```

Comment: DO you have main method in your project?

Comment: What Maven goal are you actually running? `mvn package`? Or `mvn spring-boot:repackage`? This might be helpful to reproduce the issue

Comment: I'm running mvn clean compile install which I thought ran the package goal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The release notes describe that [the `repackage` goal has an identifier now](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/wiki/Spring-Boot-2.1-Release-Notes#maven-plugin) to allow for easier overriding of the `repackage` execution.

The build above is a bit odd. If you don't want the repackage to occur, why are you defining the goal at all? Just don't define the goal and repackage will not occur as the parent only offers a default execution when the plugin is explicitly defined.

If you need to define it for a different reason, then the link above explains what you should do. Currently, you are redefining a second execution of the `repackage` goal.

Comment: Thank you for your comment.  It helped me to realize I didn't understand the repackage goal and how to use the `spring-boot-maven-plugin`.  I was using an older pom that someone else created.  I now understand I need to use the plugin's layout with none to get it to install.

Answer (score 8):

I solved this problem by using `maven-compiler-plugin` instead of `spring-boot-maven-plugin`. Still to find out what makes `spring-boot-maven-plugin` to cause this problem though.

Maven plugin details:

```
    <plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.6.1</version>
    <configuration>
    <source>1.8</source>
    <target>1.8</target>
    </configuration>
    </plugin>
```

Comment: This was what fixed it for me. I just wanted a module that has source classes without creating an executable jar, and this is what did it for me.

Comment: Made my day.. Thanks!!

Answer (score 1):

There could be 2 possibilities -

The location of source directory is wrong. You have to use the sourceSets directive to fix this. your source directory should resemble something like `src/main/java/your/package.`

OR

No `main()` method in project (if this is not lib)

Comment: Why would you need a main method for a library?  I can change the starter parent version to 2.0.8 and it builds.  
As for the directory, it does represent the above pattern.

Answer (score 0):

See if you forgot to add a default method into your SpringBoot starter-class:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
  SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
}
```